# Why is my JMeter Response Assertion not working

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to do a simple assert to check a negative instance where I get "Not found" in the Sample result and Response Data, which is expected.

I have tried:

Apply to: Main sample \ Sub-Sample

Field to Test: Text Response \ Response Code \ Response Message \ Response Header

Patterns to Test: Contains \ Substring

Pattern to Test: Not \ to \ Not Found \ found

Nothing seems to work, any idea what could be wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) above 399 as failures therefore you need to tick `Ignore Status` box if you want to mark the Sampler as successful.

Example configuration: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqdrt.png)

Also be informed that `Contains` mode of the Response Assertion assumes that you provide a [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) as input, most probably you need to switch to `Substring` instead.

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions)

Comment: thank you, Checking the Ignore Status worked.